# Does Commerce Physical Convert Imperial to Metric?

Tags: commerce

Developing a commerce for an international audience and would like to be able to show the sizes (dimenstions of the pieces) in both SI and Imperial. I was approaching this by simply having to Height and Width fields for both SI and Imperial, but wondered if this was the best approach. At least right now, I don't have to figure the dimensions into my pricing logic so I wanted to know if Commerce Physical had conversion capabilities that might let me clean up my layout a little bit? I can forsee using their logic as the site develops, but for now it's unnecessary. So, does Commerce Physical convert units? and or does anyone have advice on approaching this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commerce Physical invokes `physical_dimensions_convert` which is part of the Physical module. This provides a means to converting data between Metric and Imperial.

`physical_dimensions_convert` is on line 771 of Physical module - http://drupalcode.org/project/physical.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/physical.module#l771